# Div visible but ignored

Tags: html, css

I have a div on top of a thumbnail which displays some information. On the thumbnail I want to do drag/drop events but I can't to that because the div on top hides the selection. Is is possible to make the div visible but not interfer the drag/drop selection. I hope you understand my problem. 
I have no code because nothing is done!

Comment: I'm guessing this can done with event propegation, but if you don't show us any code we will not be able to help you. Create a small fiddle (on jsfiddle for example) to illustrate your problem and add it to the question

Comment: Please provide the link of your prblm so it will be easy to understand... :(

Comment: Look into event bubbling / propagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an element transparent to mouse interaction by adding a CSS property of `pointer-events:none`. So for example, if your div has ID `overlay`, you could use:

```css
#overlay{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can create an onclick-event for the info div that sets the focus to thumbnail, you will then be able to use the drag/drop...

Comment: Please add an example or more detail.